# php file not echoing a query from a mysql table on remote server BUT works on local XAMMP mariaDB

Tags: php, mysql

SUMMARY:

- I am new to back-end development.
- For my site, the user inputs a city location and date then clicks on the submit button for a selection of activites to do.
- City GPS coordinates are supplied by geobytes.com JSON-P API's
- The date is supplied by jQuery datepicker
- The coordinates and date are extracted within an external javascript file then passed to a PHP file (AJAX) for querying several tables, and then the results are echoed back to the webpage.
- On my local machine using XAMMP, everything works.
- On my student web space, a query on a table that uses both GPS and date DOES NOT echo

BACKGROUND:

- The PHP code is the same on both servers, except for connection
- Queries of locations tables work
- Queries of dates tables work
- One table has fields containing both GPS and date. This query does NOT echo from the school server.
- Local machine is MariaDB 10.1.38 // XAMMP v3.2.3 on windows 10)
- School mysql server version is 5.5.54 (on unix)
- PHP Version 7.3.3

```
// PHP code
// AJAX VALUES PASSED FROM JAVASCRIPT FILE`
$s = $_GET['s'];
$q = floatval($_GET['q']);
$r = floatval($_GET['r']);

// FOR MYSQL
$sqlStarParty = "SELECT sp_name, sp_location, sp_date_start, sp_nights, sp_link, sp_comment
FROM star_party 
WHERE 
sp_date_start <= DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('$s', '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
AND
sp_date_start >= DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE('$s', '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
AND
sp_latitude < ($q + 2) AND sp_latitude > ($q - 2)
AND
sp_longitude < ($r + 2) AND sp_longitude > ($r - 2)";


// TO BE ECHOED TO WEBPAGE
$resultStarParty = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlStarParty);

if (mysqli_num_rows($resultStarParty) > 0) {

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultStarParty)) {
    echo $row["sp_name"] . "<br/>";
    echo "Location : " . $row["sp_location"] . "<br/>";
    echo "Current year event start date: " . date_format(new DateTime($row["sp_date_start"]),'F, jS') . " for " . $row["sp_nights"] . " nights<br/>"; 
        echo "Details and map: " . "<a href='".$row["sp_link"]."' target='_blank'>Website</a><br/>";
        echo "<br></br>";
    }
}   // if no records match query - print 0 results
 else {
     echo "Sorry no star parties for this time and location";
}
```

EXPECTED RESULTS:

- All queries dates/location/date + location should echo to webpage.
  ACTUAL RESULTS:
- A user submits a location and date which lands on a star party event date range (+- 14 days)
- No error messages show
- No response from submit button OR no echo of star party table.
- Any help would be much appreciated!

SOLUTION:

- I was getting a 500 server error, which could be many things.
- The MySQL DB was getting the correct js variable values.
- Problem was rectified when saw that the two tables giving me grief were using `NEW DATE_TIME`.
- Change PHP code to `date_create` instead. Star party results are showing and correct.
- Thank you Paulo!

Comment: One way to debug this would be to use ChromePhp and log variables in the browser console, like the query. Another way would be to create a URL that passes those parameters manually (since they're all GET) and see what your query looks like on the server. If you don't get what you need, you probably have a query that doesn't work in that environment for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to figure out how to get ChromePhp.php include going but no luck. On chrome, I found a '500 Internal Server Error'. Waiting to hear back from webmaster.

Comment: Download `ChromePhp` and in your code, do an `include 'ChromePhp.php';` and to display variables to the console, use `ChromePhp::log($variable_name_here);`

Comment: OK the 3 inputs from the javascript file (latitude, longitude, date) are entering the php file correctly. I don't understand much of what I'm seeing. Here is the link to my project. http://student.athabascau.ca/~coreyhe/homepage.html

Comment: What do you use to query directly into the school DB? MySql Workbench, MySql command line client? Echo your query (`$sqlStarParty`) after you've formed it. Copy it and run in a client pointing to your deployment and see what error message you get.

Comment: you also say that "One table has fields containing both GPS and date. This query does NOT echo from the school server.". Can you share that query here?

Comment: I'm assuming it is MySQL command line. It is version 5.5.54 MySQL Community Server by Remi.

Comment: Here are a few queries for you to try: (1) Edmonton, AB -- Sept 24, 2019 which coincides with 2 star parties. (2) Edmonton, AB -- Sept 1, 2019 no star parties. (3) Toronto, ON -- August 31 2019, which returns a partial star party event. It is missing a couple of lines

Comment: I logged the $sqlStarParty variable and then echoed the query to the screen. I logged to the school MySQL command line and manually typed the echoed result. MySQL returned "Empty set (0.00 sec)"

Comment: forgot to say that the coordinates and date values DID get passed into sqlStarParty correctly.

Comment: Hi again, I grabbed a query with a star party event present and then put it in the school's mysql command line server and it worked... So maybe we are back to the php file? btw I've added the chromephp snippets inside the php file so you can verify

Comment: is your code even entering the `while` loop? Add a line with `echo mysqli_num_rows($resultStarParty);` before the condition to see what it's finding.

Comment: Okay I added your snippet and used swift current and aug 31/19 (has a star party event). As usual, nothing echoed. Tried aug 2/19 (no SP's) and nothing echoed. Usually those inputs yield echoes normally. I erased your snippet and then aug 2 echoed again.

Comment: fyi, the school server is using php 5.3.9 while my laptop XAMMP is using php 7.3.3

Comment: Forgot to add that there was also the usual 500 server error on the snippet aug 31  and aug 2

Comment: Here's a chromephp log for `$resultStarParty` aug 31: `mysqli_result 
{current_field: null, field_count: null, lengths: null, num_rows: null, type: null}
current_field: null
field_count: null
lengths: null
num_rows: null
type: null
__proto__: Object`

Comment: There's something wrong with your server setup. An HTTP 500 error indicates that there was a problem and it could be many things, including not able to communicate with the MySql instance. Double check your table names and layout to make sure they look the same as in your local environment.

Comment: I think I've solved it. Where date_format(new DateTime($row["op_date"]) occured, I replaced with date_format(date_create($row["op_date"]). Star Parties are showing correctly now. Hopefully this holds. Any thoughts as to why this happened? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you have a solution it is better to post an answer than to edit the question. Can you please correct this? There is an easy 'rollback' button for the question.

Comment: If you've solved this problem, post an answer and accept it; do not edit "Solved" into the title. Please follow the QA format on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved it. 
Where `date_format(new DateTime($row["op_date"])` occured, I replaced with `date_format(date_create($row["op_date"])`. Star Parties are showing correctly now. Hopefully this holds.